# Adding a start and end character to a int array and a space between each integer

Tags: java, arrays

Im creating a method where you can add a parameter char value at the start of an an int array and the end, and a string between each integer.

This is what i got so far:

```
 public static String toString(int[] a, char start, char end, String space)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
        {

            a += space;
        }
    }
```

I want it to forexample write out like this :

```
<1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10>
```

Comment: You can't use `+=` with an array, and you can't add a `String` to an `int` array.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to return a String, so declare a `String` or `StringBuilder`.
2. Add the start char to the String
3. Loop through the array and concatenate the numbers and the space.
4. Concatenate the end char
5. If `StringBuilder` is used, return with `toString()`; if `String` is used, return the String.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right kind of answer for this type of question IMO

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringBuilder`  <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/o2SmMU)</kbd> :

```
public static String toString(int[] a, char start, char end, String space)
{
    int len = a.length;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(len + (len - 1) * space.length() + 2);
    builder.append(start);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i != 0) builder.append(space);
        builder.append(a[i]);
    }

    builder.append(end);

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(toString(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, '<', '>', " - "));
```

Output:

```
<1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
String output = 
     start + Arrays.toString(a).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").replace(", ", space) + end;
```

Comment: What about his custom space character

Comment: I like it, if it works. (haven't tested it). I think my StringBuilder might beat it performance wise, though.

Comment: @crush: +1 to your answer as well.

Comment: Yours is definitely clever, and one-liners are fun. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public static String toString(int[] a, char start, char end, String space)
{
    String str = "";
    str = str+start;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        str = str+a[i]+space;           
    }
    str = str+end;
    return str;
}
```